# How to delete a record through a button in django

Tags: django

I have created a model Announcement in models.py file

```
class Announcement(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And for deleting a record of Announcement I have created the following view

```
def AnnouncementDelete(request, pk):
    announcement = get_object_or_404(Announcement, pk=pk)
    if request.method=='POST':
        announcement.delete()
        return redirect('/')
    return render(request, 'classroom/announcement_confirm_delete.html', {'announcement': announcement})
```

The delete view of announcement (that is AnnouncementDelete) has the following url

```
path("delete/<int:pk>/", view=views.AnnouncementDelete, name="AnnouncementDelete"),
```

If i enter

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/classroom/delete/3
```

on browser it is deleting the Announcement having pk = 3

Now I want a button to directly delete my record without the need of typing `http://127.0.0.1:8000/classroom/delete/3` on browser
I have tried the following methods in my allannouncement.html file

```
{% extends "classroom/base.html" %} 
{% block content %}
<h1>Announcements</h1>
{% for announcement in announcements %} 
    <!-- starting loop (posts is keyword from view) -->

  <div style="border-style: solid;">
      {% if announcement.teacher.user == request.user %}
        <div>
            <a href="{% url 'classroom:AnnouncementDelete' %}">Delete</a>
            
        </div>
      {% endif %}
      {{ announcement.pk }} 
      <a class="mr-2">Posted by: {{ announcement.teacher }}</a>
      <h2><a class="article-title">{{ announcement.title }}</a></h2>
      <p class="article-content">{{ announcement.content}}</p>
  </div>
        
{% endfor %} 
{% endblock content %}
```

but it is giving the following error

```
NoReverseMatch at /classroom/allannouncement/
Reverse for 'AnnouncementDelete' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['classroom/delete/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

then I also tried passing pk with url like

```
<a href="{% url 'classroom:AnnouncementDelete' , pk=announcement.pk %}">Delete</a>
```

But it is giving the following error

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /classroom/allannouncement/
Could not parse the remainder: ',' from ','
```

Comment: you are using post method don't forget to include button in form type of post or remove check for post method in announcementdelete view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of a link add a form.
Add

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
```

in your html file and then add

```
{% if announcement.teacher.user == request.user %}
        <div>

            <form action="{% url 'classroom:AnnouncementDelete' announcement.id %}" 
             method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="submit" value="Delete">
            </form>
            
        </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove common  #refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

```
<a href="{% url 'classroom:AnnouncementDelete' pk=announcement.pk %}">Delete</a>
```